# Extract valid words from Strings

Tags: java, string, words

Say I have 100 Strings all equal-sized(15 characters) that contain letters and spaces.

Spaces are more often than letters in each string.
Some example strings:

(In the examples below I didn't actually count the length of each string in order to be 15, but you'll the idea):

```
A       

    G

B C

OP   F   NGR

     TO

TO ATP

CAT   D O G

F   HOME OF

H O D R      IN
```

I want to extract all valid words from each string.

Valid words are those that don't include spaces, contain two or more letters and actually are English words.
Strings may contain no words, one word, or more than one word.

For example, the 5th row(string) contains the valid word: **TO**.
Same does for the 6th row. **ATP** next to **TO** is discarded because it isn't a valid word.
There is a valid word in 8th row(**CAT**), two valid words in 9th row(**HOME**, **OF**) and one valid word in 9th row(**IN**).

How can i design a function to extract these valid words?

Comment: What have you already tried to accomplish? SO isn't here to solve riddles or homework for you, but to help you achieve something when you're stuck with a problem

Comment: It is not a homework. I don't need any solution necessarily. I am given these strings that refer to a scrabble-like game. I just don't know where to start and I want you to help me think about an algorithm. Now you just "homeworked" my question having no clue what it is about. OK, thanks I guess.

Comment: My intuition would be to start with getting an array of strings, which you then can start filtering. But extracting valid words? You'd need a dictionary lookup for that or something similar

Comment: The dictionary thing is the easy part. It is just a conditional including a string and a Hashmap (dictionary). What do you mean with getting an array of strings? Do I need to convert strings to arrays? The substring solution would be similar I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class to define a regular expression which matches your definition of a word. Something like this:

```
([a-zA-z]{2,})
```

will match contiguous sequences of at least two letters (standard English alphabet only, but you can modify the pattern if you want something broader).

You can then create a [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) for each line you read in from the file and call the `find` method to see if a two-or-longer sequence is found and, if so, use the `group` method to extract the matching sequence, and the `end` method to get the offset for the next `find` call.

So far as determining whether a sequence is a valid word, you'll need to find a dictionary wordlist from somewhere (hunt around online, there are plenty of free lists). For efficiency I'd recommend reading each word from the wordlist into a `TreeSet`, then using the `contains` method of `TreeSet` to check whether each String is a valid dictionary word.

Comment: The regex didn't cross my mind. Does the Pattern class give the substring positions if a word is found? Thanks for the efficiency suggestion.

Comment: Yes, the `Matcher` object (created for each String you test) provides a method called `end` which will return the offset of the last found match by the `find` method. And one version of `find` takes an offset so you can continue searching from the last match.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and it works. You pointed me the right direction.